# Adding footer for printing web pages and setting margins

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I want to add a footer to an HTML page that will be repeated across all pages WHEN PRINTING. I have managed to achieve this through this code:

```
@media print {
    p.note {
        bottom: 0; position: fixed; 
    }
}
```

But now I have a problem with this paragraph going on top of the rest of the copy
[image]

According this Mirosoft [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd433064%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), this should work for me:

```
@page :first {
    margin-bottom: 4in;
}
```

But it doesn't, it doesn't change anything... any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the solution that worked, CSS is this:

```
@media print {
    p.note {
        display:block;
        bottom:0;
        position:fixed;
        font-size:11px;
    }
}
```

And everything needs to be contained in a separate div with this CSS

```
#wrapper {
    position:relative;
    bottom:1in;
    margin-top:1in;
    width:974px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

This worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

How about adding some z-index ? It seems that the footer overrides the last paragraph
Also try to use

```
@media print {
    p.note {
        bottom: 0; position: fixed;
margin-top:10px; 
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not overriding it, it's sitting on top of it as it is positioned on top, your answer does not help unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the container for the main content makes room for the footer. For instance, if your markup looks something like this:

```
<div id="content"><p>Lorem Ipsum Latin et cetera</p></div>
<p class="note">Footer</p>
```

You'd want some css like this:

```
#content {margin-bottom:4in}
```

Comment: There are multiple pages contained with 1 container div, I don't control the amount of stuff in it, it's all dynamic...

Comment: Regardless of the specific markup in use, you'll need to make room at the bottom for the footer - that's why it is sitting over your content. I often put everything inside `<div id="wrapper">content here</div>` for situations like this.

Answer (score 0):

To create room for your footer text you can use a `table` with `tfoot`. Use `tfoot>tr` to create a spacer. Place your footer text inside a `div` container that has `position:fixed;` to `bottom:0;`.

CSS

```
table {width:100%;}
@media print {
  tfoot>tr {height:20mm;}
  tfoot div {position:fixed;bottom:0;}
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
  <table>
    <thead><tr><td>Page header</td></tr></thead>
    <tbody><tr><td>
      <p>-</p><p>-</p><p>-</p><p>-</p><p>-</p><p>-</p><p>-</p><p>-</p><p>-</p><p>-</p><p>-</p><p>-</p><p>-</p><p>-</p><p>-</p><p>-</p><p>-</p><p>-</p><p>-</p><p>-</p><p>-</p><p>-</p><p>-</p><p>-</p><p>-</p><p>-</p><p>-</p><p>-</p><p>-</p><p>-</p><p>-</p><p>-</p><p>-</p><p>-</p><p>-</p><p>-</p><p>-</p><p>-</p>
    </td></tr></tbody>
    <tfoot><tr><td><div>Page footer</div></td></tr></tfoot>
  </table>
</body>
```