# HTML Text Footer

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML Print Header & Footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/html-print-header-footer)

How can I, like Microsoft Word does, is insert a text footer at the bottom of all my html pages. I have a long html page, that is purposely long as it is a form. But how can I, like Microsoft Word does, is insert a text footer at the end of each page, so that if I went to Print Preview in IE, I would see the text footer there on all pages. Is it even possible?

Thanks for everyones help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML Print Header & Footer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/html-print-header-footer). Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439359/adding-footer-for-printing-web-pages-and-setting-margins. Or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356881/print-header-footer-on-all-pages-print-mode. Or how about this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396322/how-to-print-footer-on-each-printed-page. And probably many many more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the css `@media` [rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html#at-media-rule) with different styles for `print` and `screen`.

An example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/html-print-header-footer)

Comment: Who downvoted that guy? Upvoted to offset.

Comment: Probably because it is a dupe. Have voted to close FWIW.